# What is the procedure for a fast landing that is too slow for go-around?

Tags: safety, landing, airbus-a320, v-speeds, go-around

Say an aircraft (A320 or similar) on landing, hits the tarmac way too fast and on a short runway, less than V2 but around V1 or slightly over. This could happen if a pilot had recently moved from Boeing and ignored the retard callout for example... or maybe the brakes just stopped working.

The situation would now be too fast to stop short of the end of runway, but too slow for a go-around.

***What is the procedure in such a scenario?***

*Since they're slower and less runway is required to pickup speed in GA aircraft, this question only really pertains to commercial airliners, an A320 or similar. (Also in GA, you can just drift into the grass and use that to slow down, again not really possible in commercial aviation)*

Comment: First, why should anyone slow below Vref? This would constitute an unstable approach. Second, why would it be too slow for go-around? Unless you have one engine failed at WAT-limited condition, you should always have enough thrust for go-around.

Comment: @JZYL Short runway, landed and then forgot to reduce thrust until halfway down it... Also, "shoulds" are not very helpful, as humans inevitably always end up not doing (or doing) things they "should"... this is what emergency procedures are for, a protocol to follow when things don't go as they "should"

Comment: Maybe I'm mistaken but the thrust required for -3deg shouldn't be too much for the brakes. Airplanes (the latest generation anyway) are designed to stop with single engine thrust runaway.

Comment: `This could happen if a pilot had recently moved from Boeing` pilots perform months or more of cross-training before being type-certified on a platform that different. At this point it's an incompetent pilot issue, not a procedure issue.

Comment: There is no V1 or V2 speed on landing. If you have the speed to fly (down to the landing) you have the speed needed to fly (as a go-aroundj. This question exhibits a misunderstanding of the basic characteristics of flying an approach, landing, and going around, and is neither answerable nor reasonable in its present form.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The system wasn't built to accommodate incompetent pilots.  Everything assumes some minimum standard of human performance.  This is like saying what if I delay getting on the brakes until 50 ft from a traffic light.  Well, you're going through into cross traffic aren't you, and no special emergency procedure is going to help you, unless you're in the Batmobile and can pull the Bat Emergency Brake Handle.

That being said, sometime pilots misjudge things and land long and well, like the late braking at the traffic light, at that point you're [going into the weeds whether you like it or not](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Air_France_Flight_358) and the emergency procedure is to scream and close your eyes.  It's a dangerous world for everybody but rocks.

Now, to answer your question, there is a procedure called "Balked Landing" which is a go-around initiated after touchdown, or before touchdown but where ground contact is assured.  You put the thrust up, accelerate to Vref, rotate and off you go, if you can.  You have to make an instant judgement call that the balked landing procedure is safer than riding it out to the end of the runway.  Usually riding it out and running off the end is the safer choice because the energy involved is much less when your world falls apart.